# Product of categorical equivalences.

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

Let $S,T$ be simplicial sets. 
Suppose $f:S\rightarrow T, f':S'\rightarrow T'$ are both categorical equivalence of simplicial sets. In the sense of [Lurie](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HTT.pdf), i.e. the induced map $\mathfrak{C}$ is an equivalence of simplicial categories.

Then is it true that 
$ S \times S' \rightarrow T \times T'$ is also a categorical equivalence?